# AngularJS rejected promise is not calling onRejection for $q.all()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have this piece of code:

```
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promises = [];

        angular.forEach($scope.devices, function(device){
            var promise = memberService.InsertDevice(memberId, device).then(function (data) {
                //device inserted
            }, function (rejectData) {
                if (rejectData.Error == "Cannot insert record since it already exists") {
                    alert("The number " + device.PhoneNumber + " already exists. Try with a different number.");
                }
            });

            promises.push(promise);
        });

        $q.all(promises).then(function (data) {
            //perform something on Success
        }, function (data) {
           //perform something on rejection
           //THIS NEVER GETS CALLED EVEN IF I GET THE ALERT FROM THE TOP
        });
```

Have a look at the last comment. For some reason, even if I get the alert (meaning that something went wrong with one of the calls) the overall rejection never gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises give the opportunity to "recover" in your failure, so you have to return a rejection in the error handle for `$q.all` to know it actually failed. The only delta in the following code is `return $q.reject(rejectData);`

```
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promises = [];

    angular.forEach($scope.devices, function(device){
        var promise = memberService.InsertDevice(memberId, device).then(function (data) {
            //device inserted
        }, function (rejectData) {
            if (rejectData.Error == "Cannot insert record since it already exists") {
                alert("The number " + device.PhoneNumber + " already exists. Try with a different number.");
            }
               return $q.reject(rejectData);
        });

        promises.push(promise);
    });

    $q.all(promises).then(function (data) {
        //perform something on Success
    }, function (data) {
       //perform something on rejection
       //THIS NEVER GETS CALLED EVEN IF I GET THE ALERT FROM THE TOP
    });
```

Comment: ohhhh return!! I was trying with just `$q.reject(rejectData);` and it wasn't working either. Makes sense though. Thanks!